# org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter service SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing

Tags: java, tomcat

We are getting the below error in Tomcat when trying to access the application. The error details are below.

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter service
SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ify.sabs.limi.app.servlets.LoginValidate.doPost(LoginValidate.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

The above issue happens when the user tries to login to the webapplication. We are using tomcat 6.0.18.0 and getting the above error.

I have also tried to run this via eclipse and got the below error

```
Jun 29, 2015 4:45:08 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter service
SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request    processing
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.authenticate(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;Lorg/apache/catalina/deploy/LoginConfig;)Z
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please share the code for `LoginValidate.java`. It says `java.lang.NullPointerException` at line 77.

Comment: Thanks all the issue is resolved. The above issue was because the application was unable to connect to the db,because the application was unable to detect the properties file due to space characters in the path to the properties file. Fixed the same and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all the issue is resolved. The above issue was because the application was unable to connect to the db,because the application was unable to detect the properties file due to space characters in the path to the properties file. Fixed the same and the issue got resolved.